# Inspecting STL containers in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, macos, stl

From googling around it looks like Xcode (3.1 in my case) should be at least trying to give me a sane debug view of STL containers - or at least vectors.

However, whenever I go to look at a vector in the debugger I just see M_impl, with M_start and M_finish members (and a couple of others) - but nothing in-between! (it's a debug build, btw).

Am I missing a setting or something somewhere?

I've also read that there are macros available that can augment the debug viewer even further to inspect more complex containers - but have been unable to find any.

I'd also like to be able to view std::wstrings, without having to drop to the memory viewer. It shows std::string fine. Is there anything I can do to show std::wstring?

I realise this is a bit of a composite question - but it's all really part of the same subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to view the container's items may rely on the complexity of the templated type.  For trivial objects like int, bool, etc., and even simple class templates like

```
template <class T> struct S { T m_t; }
```

I *normally* have no problem viewing vector items in the debugger variable view.  I say normally because there seem to be occasional bugs that cause stuff--particularly when debugging--not to behave the way I expected.  One of those things is garbage or totally useless information in the variable view.  Usually a clean rebuild of the target (or sometimes even a more drastic restarting of XCode followed by a clean rebuild) fixes the problem.

As for the other container types, it's most likely hard to efficiently view this information.  For example a map is often implemented as a red-black tree.  The debugger would have to know that in advance in order to properly walk the tree and show you all the keys and values.  That's probably asking a lot from Xcode or GDB--especially since the former focuses more on Objective-C and plain C than C++ (hence the fact that namespaces tend to kill code completion despite their ubiquity and importance).

Comment: Yeah I realise that maps and such are non-trivial, and definitely would require implementation logic (although I could imagine a system where it uses the public API to get the information out). I know that other IDEs have managed it. I thought I should at least see vectors, though.

Comment: As Visual Studio has managed to do this at least since 2008, I don't think it is expecting too much

Answer (score 2):

You can create [Data formatters](https://web.archive.org/web/20090812202145/http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/600-Viewing_Variables_and_Memory/variables_and_memory.html) for different variable types so they show up nicer :-).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the GDB debugger in Project->Edit Scheme... and consider switching your compiler to LLVM GCC 4.2 in the Project Build Settings (under Build Options -> Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C).

In XCode 4, I found I needed these settings to view things like a std::vector of V3f where V3f is a templated float vector type.

Note that I think you can't use ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) with LLVM GCC 4.2.